# Enforce part of the method in interface

Tags: c#

Is it possible to enforce part of a method through an interface?

What I am trying to do is in a simple console application, run a method from a selection of methods each from different classes derived from a common interface, and I need a way to exit the method. That, I think, requires to implement repeatedly in all the methods and I dont know how I could enforce the same logic through all.

As an example of code, this comes from a tutorial on Microsoft page on plugins:

The `Execute()` is one the method I wanna run, all other methods are the same method in diferent classes with same interface.

```cs
public class HelloCommand : ICommand
    {
        public string Name { get => "hello"; }
        public string Description { get => "Displays hello message."; }
        bool running = true;
        public bool Running { get => running; set => running = value; }

        public int Execute()
        {
            while(Running) //I would like to enforce this while loop, or similar logic
            {
                //here will be an "independent" program

                //logic to set Running to false also should be enforced, here or otherwise
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Basically I am trying to avoid repeating exit code on the Execute method, if this can be achieved on the background through abstraction or some other way I am interested as well, I cant figure a "smart" way to do it, if there is one. I dont need async or threading but if there is a good solution I welcome it.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would "repeat exit code" to clarify your question? Right now it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: what you mean? its just othe classes derived from ICommand, all with the same "exit"/return logic

Comment: I would split the command and executor and moved the execute logic to the executor (and updated the `ICommand` interface accordingly). Another option - use base class for commands and move execute there.

Comment: Oh you're talking about [`System.Windows.Input.ICommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: no, ICommand is a custom interface, [based on this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support)

Comment: Not sure about your purpose but *enforcing something* in a method implementation reminds the [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle it. You can use a base class and for example implement [the template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and move repeating logic there (though it will not prevent "custom" `ICommand` implementations which will not use the same approach).

```cs
public interface ICommand
{
    int Execute();
}

public abstract class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool Running { get; set; } = true;

    protected abstract bool ExecuteIteration(); 

    public int Execute()
    {
        while(Running)
        {
            Running = ExecuteIteration();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public class HelloCommand : BaseCommand
{
    public string Name => "hello";
    public string Description => "Displays hello message.";

    protected override bool ExecuteIteration() => false; // continue or stop
}
```

Another approach - split command and executor. Something to get you started:

```cs
public class HelloCommand : ICommand
{
    public string Name => "hello";
    public string Description => "Displays hello message.";
    
    public bool ExecuteIteration()
    {
        return false; // continue or stop
    }
}

public interface ICommand
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    bool ExecuteIteration();
}

public class Executor
{    
    public int Execute(ICommand command)
    {
        while(Running)
        {
            Running = command.ExecuteIteration();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public bool Running { get; set; } = true;
}
```

This approach can be improved/extended by changing the return type of `ExecuteIteration` to something containing more information (for example optional custom return code)

Comment: I like this answer the most

Comment: from a brief look this is the closest to what I asked since it returns each iteration to a "main" method to check if it continues, providing the default run and quit capabilities, I have to try it out to see how I incorporate the logic, thanks

Comment: I obted for removing the interface and derive all plugins from an abstract class, seems that covers my needs, example: https://sharplab.io/#gist:d963a706ed4a87da5a19cd75ca6b57b9

Answer (score 1):

make a base class, and require derived classes to override relevant parts:

```
public abstract class HelloCommand
{
    public bool Running { get; set; } = true;

    protected abstract void Run();
    
    protected abstract bool CanRun();

    public int Execute()
    {
        while(Running) //I would like to enforce this while loop, or similar logic
        {
            //here will be an "independent" program
            //logic to set Running to false also should be enforced, here or otherwise
            if (Running = CanRun())
            {
                Run();
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("over");
        return 0;
    }
}

public class GreetingsCommand : HelloCommand
{
    int count;
    public GreetingsCommand(int k = 5)
    {
        count = k;
    }

    protected override void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        count--;
    }
    protected override bool CanRun()
    {
        return count > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will try something like this

Answer (score 0):

C# 8.0 and further has default interface implementations as a test feature. To create default interface implementations, declare the interface method like an actual method, e.g.

```cs
public interface ICommand
{
    private void _OnExecute();

    int Execute()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            _OnExecute();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

P.S. your class code can be simplified to

```cs
public class HelloCommand : ICommand
{
    public string Name => "hello";
    public string Description => "Displays hello message.";
    public bool Running { get; set; }

    private void _OnExecute()
    {
        //  code for while loop
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that `HelloCommand` can override the `Execute` and then there is no actual enforcement here.

Comment: Also personally in this case I would not use the default interface methods and just have used the base class.

Comment: this would not enforce the exiting of the execute and seems that the execute loop would run forever, if I finish the` _OnExecute()` it restarts since running is still true I suppose

Answer (score 0):

You can for example create some abstract class that will implement Execute method, and will have some separate method used inside it. This separate method can have different implementations in child classes:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
    public bool Running { get; set; }

    public int Execute();
}

public abstract class AbstractCommand : ICommand
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string Description { get; }
    public abstract bool Running { get; set; }

    public int Execute()

    {
        while (Running) //I would like to enforce this while loop, or similar logic
        {
            this.SomeIndependentMethod();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    protected abstract void SomeIndependentMethod();
}

public class HelloCommand : AbstractCommand
{
    public override string Name { get => "hello"; }
    public override string Description { get => "Displays hello message."; }
    bool  running = true;
    public override bool Running { get => running; set => running = value; }

    protected override void SomeIndependentMethod()
    {
        // do some independent code here
    }
}
```

Another solution would be ommitting abstract class, and making default interface implementation of Execute method. You could implement it the same way as in that abstract class. But in that case SomeIndependentMethod would need to be a part of interface, therefore it would need to be public

Comment: this solution doesnt seem to take care of the "default exiting logic", I guess its possible as other answers suggest to use the independent method and an iteration method and to there set running to false when needs to be, but then its not enforcing overall the exiting of the execute